# How to change python3 from python3.5 to python3.6

Tags: command-line, python, python3

I have both python3.6 and python3.5 on ubuntu (zesty beta 2). I know that `python` calls python2.7. The problem is, when I call `python3`, it automatically starts python3.5 instead of python3.6.

Is there a better way to fix this than an alias?

Comment: What is wrong with aliases ?

Comment: @Ravexina Don't they slow down shells?

Comment: I'm not sure they do: [Do aliases slow down a shell's start?](https://superuser.com/questions/543649/do-aliases-slow-down-a-shells-start#543658)

Comment: Changing the system-provided version of Python risks breaking your system. Many essential system services (like apt) are tested against the system-provided version of Python. Best way to experiment with different versions of Python is in a VM.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Changing the default `python3` version might break many things on your system, and I'd advise against making `python3` point to `python3.6`. Better to simply call `python3.6` explicitly in those programs where it matters, and leave the `python3` symlink as is.

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to aliases you can use `update-alternatives`:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.6 1
```

This command will create a link in: `/usr/bin/python3` to `/usr/bin/python3.6`.

I'm not sure if it's a good idea, maybe an update makes it broken.

An other options is creating a link to desired version of python in `~/bin` then adding this path to the $PATH environment variable:

```
export PATH=/home/$USER/bin:$PATH
```

Or within your .profile:

```
PATH=/home/$USER/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: This will break things that are expecting python3 to be python3.5 (as at 17.04). For example, launching a terminal will not work and the update indicator will fail. Actually breaks apt pretty badly.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your actual question (whether it's a good idea or not, I leave aside), you can check your /usr/bin/python3 version (in my case it was 3.4 ), and replace it with the new version:

```
$ python3 -V
  Python 3.4.9

$ ls -lh /usr/bin/python3
  lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  9 Dec  5 16:35 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.4

$ sudo mv /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/_python3
$ sudo cp /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/bin/python3

$ python3 -V
  Python 3.6.6
```

Comment: It's not a good idea. Don't do this, it will break things like Gnome Terminal and APT.

Comment: @wjandrea, that's why I explicitly said to put aside "whether it's a good idea or not". I simply answered the OP question: _How to change python3 from python3.5 to python3.6 ?_

Comment: Just because you can doesn't mean you should.