# Applications don't start after boot after changing python3 symlink

Tags: python, gnome-terminal, performance

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.4 and seeing some weird behavior. After the system boots, I can't launch some applications. The system seems to be *thinking* for few seconds and then nothing happens.

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> terminal doesn't start, it doesn't start from search menu and from plank also. But from context menu on desktop (Open Terminal option) starts immediately. Also I can't start Software Updater. Firefox and Pycharm start normally.

This happened after I changed python3 link to python3.6 by running

```
sudo ln -s python3.6 python3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a number of applications on Ubuntu are based on Python, and the Python libraries they use are installed to locations specific to the version of Python being used, changing `/usr/bin/python3` or `/usr/bin/python` will likely cause a number of system-provided applications from working. Use `xterm` (which does not use Python) or the TTYs to change `/usr/bin/python3` back to `python3.5` (the default on Ubuntu 16.04), and keep it that way. (Also see: [How to change python3 from python3.5 to python3.6](https://askubuntu.com/questions/900493/how-to-change-python3-from-python3-5-to-python3-6), where the top answer advices against doing what you did.)

Comment: Yeh... its True. Changed back and now all works. Still is weird: python can't find packages in /usr/lib/python3 directory which was not moved or something...

Comment: `python` would be `python2` (... `python2.7`), unless I misunderstood what you meant.