# Upgrade to Python3.9 cannot ssh to the Ubuntu EC2 instance

Tags: 20.04, ssh, python3, amazon-ec2, cloud-init

I'm creating a custom AMI using packer and ansible. The base AMI is an Ubuntu 20.04 provided by the Canonical and it's customized using an ansible playbook.
I'm installing python3.9 and setting it as the default python:

```
        - name: Setup Python3.9 As Default Python Interpreter
      shell: |
          sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.9 1
          sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.9 2
```

Each EC2 instance based on this AMI is unreachable via ssh (I have installed openssh-server and placed the keys). Once the instance is rebooted I can ssh to the server.
The issue seams to be with the `cloud-init` package that is not working with python3.9.
What did I try?

1. Disable the `cloud-init` package - no ssh connection even after the reboot
2. Manually install the latest version of `cloud-init` - no ssh on the initial boot, ssh after the reboot worked. Got this error - `ubuntu@ip-XXX-XX-XX-XXX:~$ docker Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 28, in <module> from CommandNotFound import CommandNotFound File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py", line 19, in <module> from CommandNotFound.db.db import SqliteDatabase File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/db.py", line 5, in <module> import apt_pkg ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'`

Comment: Don't forget if you change the *default* python3 version; all Ubuntu tools that rely on that may misbehave which leads to two results (a) they won't work (best outcome) or (b) in rare cases corruption. If you change default python3, you can't use user tools like `apt` etc being limited to tools that don't use python3!   Unless you're very aware of your Ubuntu system & thus what you can/cannot use, **do not change the default python3** where you value your data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change python3 from python3.5 to python3.6](https://askubuntu.com/questions/900493/how-to-change-python3-from-python3-5-to-python3-6)

Comment: The answer was to set the specific order of things. The final goal was achieved via an external script run from Ansible playbook. 
```# !/usr/bin/env bash
set -x
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
sudo apt update
sudo apt purge -y python3-apt
sudo apt install -y python3.9
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.9 2
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.9 1
```